# django - create a model that lets you insert multiple values for the same field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Ok I'm trying to do something which should be very simple in my mind but I am probably missing some SQL or django admin knowledge to get to it. 
Say I have a simple model such as

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    review = models.TextField()
```

and I want the 'review' field in the admin site to have a little plus sign to add more reviews to the same model instance for the template to iterate through them.

I know I could create a m2m field for the reviews and it would give me just that, but I would rather like that those extra reviews could be filled from the same page without popups (for my helpless users i would like to keep it as WSIWYG as possible, since those textfields will be tinyMCE powered), and I wonder if it's really necessary to create an extra model just for a textfield

Comment: There are ways to have a text field with multiple pieces of data storing data as JSON, a list, pickled objects, etc., but you'd have to write your own getter and setter functions. 

Nothing comes with an automatic `+` sign for use in the admin like a `ModelAdmin` inline.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create a `Review` model which holds the review text and has a `ForeignKey` to `Book`...

```
class Book(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField()

class Review(models.Model):
   book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='reviews')
   review = models.TextField()
```

...then register the appropriate type of `InlineModelAdmin` to edit all the related reviews on the Book's page in the admin. I'd suggest using a `StackedInline` in this case:

```
class ReviewInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Review

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ReviewInline,
    ]
```

The documentation has an example of almost this exact scenario, except for multiple authors instead of multiple reviews:

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: This is definitely the way to go.

Comment: can this be possible for a model which has both foreign keys

Comment: can you give an image of how it looks like on admin site

Answer (score 0):

Another option since Django 3.1. could be creating a JSON field and storing multiple values in a key value pair. Although it may not be suitable for all cases but for some that came to this topic it could work. Reference to Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield