# How can I make multiple value field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, multivalue-database

How can I make a field that can accept more than one input and connect it to my database? 
For example : I want to make a field that is called 'user_skills' and the user can enter more than skil in that field .. How can I do that?

Comment: You need a many to many relationship, you can find info about that here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django - create a model that lets you insert multiple values for the same field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090047/django-create-a-model-that-lets-you-insert-multiple-values-for-the-same-field)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the `Database` you are using. If you are using `postgresSql` you can do this with `ArrayField` [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/)

Other possible options can be use JsonField or try to use normalize Model where you can store pre-define value's of corresponding field and can access them with `ManyToManyField`.