# How to create multivalued field using django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i want to create a user registration api using django rest-framework,having fields name,email,address and other.
I want to make the other field multivalued input field so that this field can take multple input in api.
i used this model

```
class User(models.Model):
    Name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    otherAddress=models.ForeignKey('self')
```

i want my api field should be like
1)Name
2)email
3)address
4)other-->taking more than one or two inputs

Comment: A multivalued field would ensure that your database would not even conform to the first normal form(1 NF). Why do you want to do that?

Comment: so that i can register multiple friends name of user. say i m the user and i have 5 friends,so i m the primary person and my other 5 friends are secondary  and they will recognise by my identity(email,address)

Comment: You can use a separate data model for friends(of the user) and link it to User model by Foreign key instead.

Comment: i used that but during entering data in api  i got other field as drop down. but i want to enter data in that field also. may be i lag in serializer

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090047/django-create-a-model-that-lets-you-insert-multiple-values-for-the-same-field) for more details.

Comment: and how i will use this model in serializable.py because i m new to framework

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django - create a model that lets you insert multiple values for the same field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090047/django-create-a-model-that-lets-you-insert-multiple-values-for-the-same-field)