# In django which model feilds is required for data which having comma like in csv file 1 colunm having multiple data i.e. French, Japanese, Desserts

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-database

I am creating CRUD api in django rest framework sqlite3 database. I want to create model for restaurant which having some feilds which is [Restaurant ID, Restaurant Name, Cuisines, Average Cost for two, Currency, Has Table booking, Has Online delivery, Aggregate rating, Rating color, Rating text, Votes]

i have csv file which is already having data but which model feild is required for Cuisines because under Cuisines colunm having multiple list

[csv file rows and columns please check Cuisines column and what type of model feild is required for this column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKMSZ.jpg)

above image having data which is available in csv file

```
    class Restaurant(models.Model):
        restaurant_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        restaurant_name = models.TextField()
        Cuisines = models.TextField()
        average_cost_for_two = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        currency = models.CharField(max_length=130)
        has_table_booking = models.CharField(max_length=130)
        has_online_delivery = models.CharField(max_length=130)
        aggregate_rating = models.FloatField(default=0)
        rating_color = models.CharField(max_length=130)
        rating_text = models.CharField(max_length=130)
        votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

in above model class which feild is required for Cuisines

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding properly, what you want is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090047/django-create-a-model-that-lets-you-insert-multiple-values-for-the-same-field). A field where you can have multiple choices.

Rather than a field that can have multiple data, what you can do, as stated in the other question I linked is to create another model Cuisine that has a foreign key to the restaurant.

```
class Cuisine(models.Model):
     type = models.CharField(max_length=130)
     restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, related_name='Cuisines')
```

So you can have multiple cuisines linked to the same restaurant.